# Spark job hangs indefinitely on rdd takeSample

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I want to select a random sample of files from a hdfs path. The following is a snippet of code which compiles and adds every file which matches the wildcard into my RDD.

```
PATH_TO_RAW_DATA = "hdfs:/user/myname/documents/d*"
tf = sc.binaryFiles(PATH_TO_RAW_DATA, 100000)
```

This contains ~5000 files and compiles correctly

I want to select a random sub-ample of the above RDD, say 100 files.

Te following code is what I'm using to do this:

```
PATH_TO_RAW_DATA = "hdfs:/user/myname/documents/d*"
tf = sc.binaryFiles(PATH_TO_RAW_DATA, 100000)
tf = tf.takeSample(False, 100, seed = 1)
```

According to the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/api/pyspark/pyspark.rdd.RDD-class.html#takeSample), this should give me an RDD with 100 documents from the original RDD.

I am, however, getting the error: `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

Is this a bug in Spark/Pyspark or am  I incorrectly using this function?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would suggest to reduce the parallelism

```
      tf = sc.binaryFiles(PATH_TO_RAW_DATA, 100000)
```

Unless the data is extremely huge there is no reason of making 1 million partitions. Having too many partitions is counter productive.

Increase the driver memory, java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space is happening most probably because of the takeSample not able to get 100 items to the driver. So try increasing the driver memory could solve the issue. 
Otherwise try to take lesser sample, take 10 instead 100 and see if that works